# How to speed up the Dash response?

Tags: unity

Is there a way to speed up the Dash? When I press the super key for the first time it can take ~2 seconds for the dash to appear. Whereas if I use Synapse, it will appear instantly.

Answer (score 25):

### Ubuntu 12.10

---

**I. Install [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/)**. Type in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install unsettings
```

Open Unsettings. You can try 2 changes.

- First, go to Dash > Blur and select *No blur*.

[image: No blur]

- Second, go to Themes and change Graphics Mode to *Force low graphics mode*.

[image: Low graphics mode]

**II. Install the Compiz Config Settings Manager**. Type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open the compiz manager. Go to OpenGL and select Texture Filter > Fast

[image: Texture filter]

Remember to log out!

Comment: "changing Graphics Mode to Force low graphics mode." is not available in 12.04 Unsettings 0.08

Comment: Doesn't work for 13.10 - I guess there's no saucy branch.

Comment: also doesn't install for 14.04

Comment: It's much faster after setting `no blur`, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Deactivating the "blur" effect might help.

To do so install "MyUnity" in the Ubuntu Software Center. Then you can disable the blur effect by setting the "Blur" option on the "dash"-tab to "Off".

[Here's a screenshot](http://static.kendoo.bheil.net/201217238/imagehost/myunity-disable-blur-effect.png):
[image: window screenshot showing disabling of blur effect]

Comment: Thanks it improves slightly.  Does changing the swapiness factor can have an effect?

Comment: [MyUnity is no longer available as of 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/a/203718/116961).

Comment: You can switch off dash blur in compizconfig-settings-manager too.

Answer (score 6):

## Ubuntu 12.04LTS

**Unity Dash** in Ubuntu 12.04LTS (*Unity 5*) may lack the swiftness and fluidity of later Unity versions like Ubuntu 14.04LTS's *Unity 7*, but it's stable enough for everyday use. Before you try the steps for improving Unity's speed, it's recommended to update Unity and Compiz to their latest versions available on Ubuntu 12.04LTS's repositories. This is because initial versions of Unity 5 had stability problems, but later ones received stability and speed improvements backported from successive Ubuntu releases. By the time final release of Ubuntu 12.04LTS (12.04.5) was out, Unity (v5.20) had gotten quite solid and stable.

Some of the steps suggested here require [Compiz Config](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/). You can also use other tools like MyUnity, Unsettings, Ubuntu Tweak or editing the schema/settings directly through *dconf-editor* or *gsettings*. But, I recommend **Compiz Config**, coz it allows  you to edit all Compiz and Unity settings in one place. Click here to install [Compiz Config](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install Compiz Config]

[image: Compiz Config Unity Plugin Settings Experimental Tab]

**Step 1: Deactivate Dynamic Blur**:
This would reduce lag and stutter experienced when using Dash. Open ***Compiz Config -> Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> Experimental Tab -> Dash Blur*** and change it to *Static Blur* or *No Blur*.

- *Static Blur* causes a flicker bug with some graphics drivers in Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Otherwise, this would've been the best choice.
- *No Blur* makes Dash transparent. As a result, you may need to increase the opacity or darkness of the Dash to improve visibility. This can be done by changing the color value in *Compiz Config -> Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> Experimental Tab -> Background Color* option.

**Step 2: Remove unwanted Lens and Scopes**:
The Dash in Ubuntu 14.04LTS provides an option to disable/enable **Scopes**. Unfortunately, this feature isn't available in 12.04LTS's Unity. However, they can still be manually disabled by editing each individual lens' setting under *dconf-editor->desktop->unity->lenses*. But, I prefer to remove the unwanted **Lens** and **Scopes** altogether.

- Uninstall **unity-scope-musicstores** and **unity-scope-video-remote**.
  If your Ubuntu machine isn't connected to internet very often or if you don't need these services, just remove them.
- Uninstall **unity-lens-music** and **unity-lens-video**
  The File Lens can still show all your music and videos, and filter them too. You don't need those lenses unless you're a real big music or video lover.

**Step 3: Reduce Dash Startup Delay**:
You might have noticed that Dash takes a long time to load when used for the first time after booting. This **startup delay** can be reduced by using **preload** or similar daemons. Click here to install [preload](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/preload) [image: Install Compiz Config]

**Step 4: Reduce Graphics Settings**:
If all the previous steps didn't improve speed noticeably, or if you are still hungry for more performance, reduce the Graphics Settings for **Compiz**. I got this idea from [Ed Villegas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153831/how-to-speed-up-the-dash-response/235765#235765)' [Answer for Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/users/26383/ed-villegas). But remember, this change affects graphics quality of the entire Ubuntu system, not just Unity alone! Open ***Compiz Config->OpenGL->Texture Filter*** and set it to *Fast*.

[image: Reduce Compiz Graphics Settings Level]

After doing all the above **restart** the system before checking the results, or else Unity may behave abnormally.

Note that Ubuntu 12.04LTS's *Unity 5* doesn't have a *Low Graphics Mode* like that of Unity 7 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. However, 12.04LTS provides a similar looking but very different Unity2D desktop, which runs on a different Window Manager instead of Compiz. You may use it if your graphics hardware is very weak. But, I wouldn't recommend using it under normal cases.

Answer (score 3):

There may not be anything to do for that.

If the Dash hasn't been used for a while, it is possible its code has been evicted from memory to make room for something else used recently.  If that is the case it has to grab that back from disk before it is able to act.

Again, there may not be a workaround that would solve it without adding some other slowdown because of memory usage manipulation.

Comment: No, this is not the problem. Even on [high-end systems with copious amounts of RAM](http://askubuntu.com/a/138617/116961), and even when used continuously, the dash is slow, and that's primarily due to animations done in a lame way.

Comment: Actually that is the problem for some people. My system is a core i7 with loads of RAM, but when the backup kicks in the cache is used up and apps get pushed out from the cache. Pressing the Super key (which I don't do often) causes it to page in the necessary memory and that introduces a delay.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two bugs reported for this long-standing problem (goes back to 2012). Please consider adding yourselves to the bugs to bump the matter as there seems not to be much attention paid to it from the developers:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/814833

https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/919801

Answer (score 1):

The dash is slow due to the extra high end graphics which your graphics card supports with much difficulty. Add the following line to the `.xprofile` file in your home directory.(In case its not present the create it).

```
export UNITY_LOW_GFX_MODE=1
```

The above line will enable low graphics mode which can be easily supported by your GPU. Dont worry you will not loose any image quality in case you are fearing so :)

And save it and logoff and login again. And now check. Your Dash home would work fast and smooth.

Comment: Nope. very little improvement, if any. Typing in dash is still laggy and dash still takes ~2 secs to pop up. Plus it's buggy, I have the launcher on autohide, and doing what you say leaves a black line all the way down the screen where the edge of the launcher is supposed to be.