# How do I install Myunity on 12.10?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, add-apt-repository, myunity

Basically as is the title how do you install **Myunity** on **12.10**? I've tried adding the repository `ppa:myunity/ppa` and performing:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

At which point I received the **error**:

```bsh
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/myunity/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Myunity depends on `gambas2` but Ubuntu 12.10 release comes with `gambas3`

Myunity packages are not supported for 12.10 release hence they are [removed from here](https://launchpad.net/myunity)

So by adding PPA wont help you to install Myunity.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of going through all that headache install something that works as well as My Unity and is supported for Quantal, [**Unsettings**](http://florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/index.html) has its own ppa at https://launchpad.net/~diesch/+archive/testing

Answer (score 4):

According to [Here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/radiotray/+question/211717), the PPAs don't yet support Quantal, you can check this link to see what ubuntu versions are supported:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/myunity/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

There is no Quantal (12.10) there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Unsettings, and it is quite powerful (i.e. - quite a ways more powerful than the screenshot makes it look like initially, I think). I definitely recommend trying it.

I had earlier found out that it is also possible to have CompizConfig Settings Manager on Ubuntu 12.10.

It can be installed with the command

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Once it is installed it can be started with the command `ccsm`

Once CompizConfig Settings Manager is started, you can select the "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" under the desktop section, and that shows several Unity configuration options.