# Questions on first install

Tags: myunity

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.10 64bit on dual boot with windows 7. 
I've been looking for a lot of the things people say to download, like myunity 
but when I search in the software center, nothing comes up, just stuff like magazines. 
Do I need to add some ppas for it to see them? 
What are some that I should add on a new install?

And can anyone help me get myunity on here so I can start customising my desktop? 
Thanks

Comment: The MyUnity application doesn't [support Ubuntu 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203709/how-do-i-install-myunity-on-12-10?rq=1) yet. There aren't any recommended PPA, you just add or remove them as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myunity is not supportable currently But you can use Ubuntu Tweak, it is also nice tool for customization.

Just Run following commands in terminal to Install **Ubuntu Tweak**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
```

Here add-apt-repository  adds repository

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: I even saw people on youtube saying to use myunity. is it just not updated for 12.10 yet?