# How do I minimize all windows in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys

Does anyone know the good working way to minimize all windows in Ubuntu 12.10 ? I saw a few articles and didn't find any valuable. For example,

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work.
2. **System** ➜ **Preferences** ➜ **Keyboard Shortcuts** - doesn't exist in Ubuntu
   12.10.
3. `CompizConfig Manager` doesn't work properly, it sometimes doesn't
   minimize all windows for some reason. Besides, it's not recommended to use it (it was said here on AskUbuntu)

Comment: Doesn't Alt+D work?

Comment: Try <Ctrl><Super><D> again.  It's really picky.  You have to press them all at the *exact* same  time.

Comment: @Seth, it doesn't work. Besides, it's very difficult to press them at the same time for a such simple job.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the vanilla/generic Unity or compiz installation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `MyUnity`. I don't know if your keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will work then, but you will get an icon in the launcher:
See this question:
[How to add a “Show desktop” icon to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126540/how-to-add-a-show-desktop-icon-to-the-launcher)

Comment: I can't install it - http://askubuntu.com/questions/203709/how-do-i-install-myunity-on-12-10

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed 12.10, and I've found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> works to minimize all windows. Perhaps there is a typo in the help documentation, or the shortcut was improperly coded?