# No packages are installing

Tags: apt, 14.04, myunity

I am trying to install MyUnity, but it won't install by `apt-get install myunity`. I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
[sudo] password for savageowl: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package myunity
```

Even more weird is that MyUnity is also found in the Software Center, and when I search for it, it's not there. I also found a link that launches Software Center and sends you to MyUnity, and I got and error saying I dont have it. The same thing happened with Skype,  but I managed to get that installed from a debian package.

Comment: Last Ubuntu version supported was 12.04. Read also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203709/how-do-i-install-myunity-on-12-10)

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install myunity
```

I guess they can help. As may be [this site](http://ppa.launchpad.net/myunity/ppa/ubuntu/dists/).

Then use your commands:

```
sudo apt-get install myunity
```