# How to fix lag in 'Dash Home'?

Tags: unity, nvidia, unity-dash

I have Ubuntu 12.04. I'm experiencing large lag within the dash home screen, particularly around the icons and typing lag within search. Otherwise it is smooth outside this area.

I've tried various things within CCSM such as disabling blur, detect refresh rate and Sync to VBlank but still get lag. Is this due to my graphics drivers? Some system info:

Specs:

- Mem: 7.8GiB
- Proc: Intel Core i7 CPU 860
- OS: 64-bit
- SSD
- Graphics: GeForce 6200LE

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you running 'System Monitor' in the background? I have found that the dash suffers from lag when system monitor is open.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, I'm barely running anything. The system seems laggy in general, but extremely so in the dash home section. Would using the 32-bit version help? Or just get a better graphics card?

Comment: I suffer of this same problem, although not so serious lag as you describe. The only way I've been able to make the dash home run smoothly is to login with Unity 2D.

Comment: This is probably related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/814833. Please check if you can relate and add your subscription. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used unity 2d instead of 3d and the lag within dash home disappears. I'm guessing this is a graphics card problem? What graphics cards are best for Ubuntu?

Comment: You should add that it's **always** a graphics card issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Why is the dash so unresponsive, and is there a way to fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127170/why-is-the-dash-so-unresponsive-and-is-there-a-way-to-fix-this), I fixed the problem by installing [Compiz config setting manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) and disabling "Fading windows" under "Effects".