# Is there a simple way to diagnose Unity performance issues?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, performance

The Unity Dash and HUD are slow to open, sometimes freezing the system for up to four seconds when I first hit the Alt or Super keys.  Is there a simple way to find out where the time is going?

The folks in #ubuntu-unity advised that I could run `valgrind --tool=callgrind compiz --replace` to generate a profile of the application, however I want a simpler place from which to start troubleshooting.

Comment: 1st try clearing off the record history in `System Settings --> Privacy`. If that doesnot do the trick try disabling the **RECORD ACTIVITY** at the bottom. I think it might be due to **Zeitgeist Datahub**

Comment: let me know if that works!

Comment: Try this:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/55342/unitys-dash-is-slow-and-taking-couple-of-seconds-until-its-shown

Comment: This question has been answered [several](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55342/unitys-dash-is-slow-and-taking-couple-of-seconds-until-its-shown) [times](http://askubuntu.com/a/138617/116961)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the dash so unresponsive, and is there a way to fix this?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127170/why-is-the-dash-so-unresponsive-and-is-there-a-way-to-fix-this)

Comment: It could be low memory - the disk grinds if I try to bring up the HUD, Dash, or even the application switcher.  But how do I prove or disprove it?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the HUD was extremely slow when fading in and out. I solved it by installing Compiz Config and doing the following:

1. Disabling Animations and Fading Windows
2. Under Ubuntu Unity Plugin, setting the "Dash Blur" to "No Blur"
3. Under Open GL, changing the texture filter to "Fast" and unchecked Framebuffer object.